# Adding a horizontal dashed line in a tikz picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

[image]I'm trying to add a red horizontal dashed line at 3.0283 in the tikz picture with code below. The options I've tried to far have either not compiled or made one dash at (0,3.0283). Any suggests extremely grateful! Thank you in advance.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.15}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
 \centering
\pgfplotsset{width=17cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{semilogxaxis}[log basis x=2, xmin=2^4, xmax=2^18, ymin=1.5, ymax= 4.3, xlabel={Number Iterations}, ylabel={Expected Value of European Call}]
\addplot+[only marks, color=black, mark options={fill=black}, error bars/.cd, y dir=both,y explicit]
coordinates {
(2^5, 2.575426873) +- (0,0.879134009)
(2^6, 3.248958815) +- (0,0.878972497)
(2^7, 2.777192212) +- (0,0.538995365)
(2^8, 3.087205046) +- (0,0.430526707)
(2^9, 2.839813099) +- (0,0.271699898)
(2^10, 2.99962185) +- (0,0.200001514)
(2^11, 3.036591208) +- (0,0.142075497)
(2^12, 2.995606084) +- (0,0.101353885)
(2^13, 3.019666878) +- (0,0.069387224)
(2^14, 3.079018363) +- (0,0.050965547)
(2^15, 3.001740643) +- (0,0.035138634)
(2^16, 3.029783754) +- (0,0.025229816)
(2^17, 3.027393515) +- (0,0.017812922)
};
\addplot[black,dashed]coordinates {(0,3.0283)--(2^18,3.0283)};
\end{semilogxaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Estimations with $95\%$ Confidence Intervals}
\label{errors}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just add a constant with `\addplot[black,dashed,domain = 2^4:2^18,samples = 2] {3.0283};`.

[image: plot]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.15}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
 \centering
\pgfplotsset{width=17cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{semilogxaxis}[log basis x=2, xmin=2^4, xmax=2^18, ymin=1.5, ymax= 4.3, xlabel={Number Iterations}, ylabel={Expected Value of European Call}]
\addplot+[only marks, color=black, mark options={fill=black}, error bars/.cd, y dir=both,y explicit]
coordinates {
(2^5, 2.575426873) +- (0,0.879134009)
(2^6, 3.248958815) +- (0,0.878972497)
(2^7, 2.777192212) +- (0,0.538995365)
(2^8, 3.087205046) +- (0,0.430526707)
(2^9, 2.839813099) +- (0,0.271699898)
(2^10, 2.99962185) +- (0,0.200001514)
(2^11, 3.036591208) +- (0,0.142075497)
(2^12, 2.995606084) +- (0,0.101353885)
(2^13, 3.019666878) +- (0,0.069387224)
(2^14, 3.079018363) +- (0,0.050965547)
(2^15, 3.001740643) +- (0,0.035138634)
(2^16, 3.029783754) +- (0,0.025229816)
(2^17, 3.027393515) +- (0,0.017812922)
};
\addplot[black,dashed,domain = 2^4:2^18,samples = 2] {3.0283};
\end{semilogxaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Estimations with $95\%$ Confidence Intervals}
\label{errors}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Note: Due to the logarithmic axis it will cause an error if you try to start at `x = 0`.

Comment: Amazing thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! I'm happy I could help.

Comment: In case this solution works for you, you can accept the answer by clicking the check mark. ;-)